# Grouping / nesting get functions

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am extending (sorry for wrong names coming from other languages, I am new in JS) `Page` Object, by adding a lot of functions, for example `firstLevelFunction1` and `firstLevelFunction2`. My goal is to group these functions, so that I can access them by dot like this: `firstLevelGroup.secondLevelFunction1`. I created `firstLevelGroup` in the same way as `firstLevelFunction`. Function `testLevels` is just to verify behavior on different levels, when I call it the output is:

> first level function1
>   first level function2
>   { get: [Function: get] }
>   { get: [Function: get] }

while I expect:

> first level function1
>   first level function2
>   second level function1
>   second level function2

My code:

```js
let Page = require('./../page')
let JsTestingPage = Object.create(Page, {

    firstLevelFunction1: {get: function () { return 'first level function1' }},
    firstLevelFunction2: {get: function () { return 'first level function2' }},

    firstLevelGroup: { get: function () {
        return {
            secondLevelFunction1: {
                get: function () {
                    return 'second level function1'
                }
            },
            secondLevelFunction2: {
                get: function () {
                    return 'second level function2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    },
    testLevels: {value: function () {
        console.log(this.firstLevelFunction1)
        console.log(this.firstLevelFunction2)
        console.log(this.firstLevelGroup.secondLevelFunction1)
        console.log(this.firstLevelGroup.secondLevelFunction2)
    }}

})
module.exports = JsTestingPage
```

I also tried other versions, with no success. The one above does not return an error at least.

Please advise me what to do to group functions. Also, feel free to say that it makes no sense to group functions at all :)
BTW, this structure (first level) comes more or less from webdriver.io framework. Grouping functions to second level is my idea to make file more clear and structured.

Comment: Thank you for quick and precise answer. It works as expected. Then I must decide if it is really more clear. If you want please add it as an answer so that I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: About semicolons - I come from Java and for me it is also more clear with semicolons. But this is my company policy and I must adapt (eslint underscore semicolons)

Comment: Uh ... That's an awful policy, omitting semicolons can introduce bugs hard to debug.

Comment: I will try to change it, when I learn JS a bit more. Now I am newbie without any influence ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thank you for help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens beacuse you're returning an object initializer, where `get` becomes an ordinary method name, it doesn't create a getter to the inner objects. To fix this, wrap the returned object within `Object.create(null, {...})` (or use a more meaningful prototype, if provided), and you'll get what you're expecting.

```js
let JsTestingPage = Object.create(null, {
  firstLevelFunction1: {
    get: function() {
      return 'first level function1';
    }
  },
  firstLevelFunction2: {
    get: function() {
      return 'first level function2';
    }
  },
  firstLevelGroup: {
    get: function() {
      return Object.create(null, {
        secondLevelFunction1: {
          get: function() {
            return 'second level function1';
          }
        },
        secondLevelFunction2: {
          get: function() {
            return 'second level function2';
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
  testLevels: {
    value: function() {
      console.log(this.firstLevelFunction1);
      console.log(this.firstLevelFunction2);
      console.log(this.firstLevelGroup.secondLevelFunction1);
      console.log(this.firstLevelGroup.secondLevelFunction2);
    }
  }
});
JsTestingPage.testLevels();
```

Or alternatively create the getters inside the object initializers:

```
firstLevelGroup: {
    get: function() {
        return {
            get secondLevelFunction1 () {
                return 'second level function1';
            },
            get secondLevelFunction2 () {
                return 'second level function2';
            }
        }   
    }
},
```